# XnView - how to fit images to window?

Tags: stretch, xnview

How can I tell XnView MP to stretch small images so they fit the window?

The program is resizing the big images to fit the window but it doesn't stretch the small images to fit the window.

Is there an option for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XnView has two settings regarding stretching images, one for regular windows `View` and a second time for `Fullscreen` view.

Change the entry `Auto image size` - I assume what you want is the setting `Fit image to window`.

[image]